# MySQL not updating using prepare

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database named records with a table named records. That table has 3 columns named id, firstname, lastname.

When I to update with

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
        {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);

            if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')
            {
                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $error, $id);
            }
            else
            {
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE players SET firstname = ?, lastname = ? WHERE id=?"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $firstname, $lastname, $id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                }

                header("Location: view.php");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
        {
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE id=?"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->bind_result($id, $firstname, $lastname);
                $stmt->fetch();

                renderForm($firstname, $lastname, NULL, $id);

                $stmt->close();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: view.php");
        }
    }
```

It looks like it updates with no errors but when I look in the database it has not been updated. Same if i try and add a new recorded. But I can delete a record. Using

```
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM players WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
```

I am using this to connect to the db

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'records';

$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
```

Hope I have cover everything okay. First time I have tried to use a prepared statement so I must be missing something. Strange that the delte works but the other two do not.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: You said the table name is *records*, but in your query you're doing `UPDATE players SET ...`. Change your update query to `UPDATE records SET ...`.

Comment: You're also checking to see if `$_GET['id']` is set, but checking the value of `$_POST['id']` is numeric. Are you really using both GET and POST?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bind\_param() doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710437/bind-param-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: _I have a database named **records** with a **table** named **records**_ But you are attempting to update a table called `players` So where did that come from

Comment: we also don't know if your POST/GET arrays contain values. Again, check for errors.

Comment: Is `id` a `GET` or `POST` seem to be interchanging that.. `if (isset($_GET['id']))` then `if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))`.

Comment: I still get no errors. Is there a way to echo those GET and POST id's so I can see what the are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad!!!!!!
I use phpstorm as my editor. When I created the project I forgot to create it on my local server, so that is why the database was not getting updates. When I move it to the correct place it works fine.

Really really sorry.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to show all errors and warnings

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
...
```

also

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
   trigger_error('Database connection failed: '.$mysqli->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

I assume your `$_POST['id']` and `$_GET['id']` are equals. Both numeric and more than zero. Comment or remove `header('location: view.php');` first and see what error comes. Or just move it to where you successfully execute query. I change the code a bit to my style.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


if(!isset($_GET['id']) && !is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] < 1){
    header("location: view.php");
    exit();
}
$id = $_GET['id']; //is set, is numeric, is more than zero

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['id'] == $id){ //$_POST['id'] = $_GET['id'];
    $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);

    if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == ''){
        $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
        renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $error, $id);
    }else{
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `players` SET `firstname` = ?, `lastname` = ? WHERE `id`=?")){
            $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $firstname, $lastname, $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            header("location: view.php"); //redirect only if query success
        }else{
            echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
        }
    }
}else{
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `id`=?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result(); //you were missing this
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $firstname, $lastname);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        renderForm($firstname, $lastname, NULL, $id);
        header("location: view.php"); //redirect only if query success
    }else{
         echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
    }
}
?>
```

However, I personally rather check the value of `id` first on database. If it does exist, then run the stuff if I wish to retrieve value from `$_GET` method. This confusion happens because you have both `$_GET` and `$_POST` method to get value of `id`.

Comment: I added your code into new php file and I get the same results to error and not update.