# Error updating table with INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I'm relatively new to mySQL.  For some reason, I'm getting an error with my INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command.  This is what it looks like:

```
print "Writing status to file \n";
$mysqliNode = new mysqli('blah.net', 'us', 'pw', "CATV_Mon");
$stmtNode = $mysqliNode->prepare("INSERT INTO CATV_Mon.nodeDetail (nodID, pctRedYellow, count)
                                  VALUES (?,?,?) 
                                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pctRedYellow   = VALUES(percentRedYellow)
                                                         ,count     = VALUES(count)                               
                                  ");
$index = "ABCF";
$tempCount = 5000; 
$node_percent_down = 55;
$stmtNode->bind_param("sss",$index,$node_percent_down,$tempCount);
if(!$stmtNode->execute) {
        $tempErr = "Error getting Node $nod info and put in table: " . $stmtNode->error;
        printf($tempErr . "\n");    //show mysql execute error if exists  
        $err->logThis($tempErr);
        printf ("will die on purpose now \n");  
        die();          
} //if stmtNode didn't execute ok
```

When I run it, I see (it's not showing an error message):

```
Writing status to file
Error getting Node WILL info and put in table:  
will die on purpose now
```

I tried using the statement in MySQL Workbench:

```
INSERT INTO CATV_Mon.nodeDetail (nodID, pctRedYellow, count)
                                  VALUES ("ABCE",30,5000) 
                                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pctRedYellow   = VALUES(pctRedYellow)
                                                         ,count     = VALUES(count) ;
```

And that works, and says 1 row(s) affected and I see it in the table. When I change the values to update and run it in workbench, it updates what is changed and looks good in the table.

Any ideas why it's failing in the php script?  i tried changing the nodeID I'm trying to insert and it fails similarly.

The table structure is:
nodID          varchar(20) primary key
pctRedYellow   int(5)
count          int(8)

I searched online and it looks like I'm doing what I'm supposed to do.  [insert on duplicate key update](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/). I was thinking I needed WHERE in my statement, but it's working in workbench, and looks good with the syntax at the link.

Comment: `bind_param("sss",$index,$node_percent_down,$tempCount);` variables `$node_percent_down` and `$tempCount` are ints so try `bind_param("sii",$index,$node_percent_down,$tempCount);` instead like the manual says table "Type specification chars" "i  corresponding variable has type integer" source http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Also output the error message where you have the ```printf ("will die on purpose now \n");```, then edit your question to show the full error text

Comment: I tried sii and it still has the same issue: Writing status to file
Error getting Node WILL info and put in table:  
will die on purpose now

Comment: @SloanThrasher - that's the weird thing...it's not printing an error message there.

Answer (score 1):

I found this, and it fixed it.  [bind param doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710437/bind-param-doesnt-seem-to-work)

$stmtNode->bind_param('sii', $index, $node_percent_down, $tempCount);